# Compilation error, list not recognised

Tags: java, import

I am using the [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) collections, and more specifically, its primitive arrayList for ints.

The declaration of the list is as follows:

```
TIntArrayList list= new TIntArrayList();
```

However, I am facing a compilation error I cannot explain.  When I declare the list as follows:

```
import gnu.trove.list.array.TIntArrayList;

public class Main {

   TIntArrayList list= new TIntArrayList();
}
```

, the code runs correctly as expected.  However, when I declare the list (with different import statement) as follows:

```
import gnu.trove.*; 

public class Main {

    TIntArrayList list= new TIntArrayList();
}
```

, a compilation error appears about not recognising TIntArrayList.

I was wondering why this error appears?  I thought that by using `*` the list should be recognized.  This error doesn't appear when `java.util.*;` is used instead of `java.util.arrayList;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the `*` does not import sub-levels, but only everything in the current level.  If you used `import gnu.trove.list.array.*`, it would work as you expect.

The reason it works on `java.util.*` is because the `ArrayList` class is in the same folder as the wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

The `.*` addition only counts for all classes in the directory representing that package name. Java package names aren't really directories, directories are just used to organize classes.